# Can't find module googleapis

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-authentication

This is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var Session = require('express-session');
var google = require('googleapis');
var plus = google.plus('v1');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
```

This is an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'googleapis'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/software/Harsh Patel/test/demo_auth/server.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

I tried to reinstall modules with these methods

1. `npm install googleapis --save`
2. `npm install googleapis`
3. `npm install` (add module to package.json file)

but these methods didn't work.

I found the googleapis module in the `node_modules` directory.

Comment: I write the code for my self

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried it myself, got the same problem. After looking at *node_modules/googleapis/package.json* I found out, that *node_modules/googleapis/lib/googleapis.js* file is missing. Reinstalling googleapis wasn't helping.

Solution for me was to build googleapis. To do that, navigate to `./node_modules/googleapis` directory and execute 2 commands:

1. `npm i typescript -g`
2. `npm run build`

Comment: Run these 2 commands: 
`npm i  typescript -g` and then 
`tsc ./node_modules/googleapis/lib/googleapis.ts`

Comment: I got another error "apirequest.ts(15,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'"

Comment: You can ignore errors you get when running `tsc`. After running `tsc`, check if there is _googleapis.js_ file in `./node_modules/googleapis/lib` folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps me out