# Error with google-api-nodejs-client

Tags: node.js, npm, google-api

I have a same problem as in this question: [Can't find module googleapis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818791/cant-find-module-googleapis)

I tried to implement the [Max's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819023/3266847), but when I run `npm run build` as in

```
npm i typescript -g
npm run build
```

I get this error in the log:

```
 verbose stack Error: missing script: build
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find other solution for first question [Can't find module googleapis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818791/cant-find-module-googleapis) run this command: `npm i -S googleapis@30.0.0` in `npm_modules` folder

Answer (score 1):

Check your `package.json` :
`"scripts"` should have an object where your scripts are defined.
That error means `"build"` is not defined in that object.

When you type

```
npm run something
```

npm searches for `something` defined there and executes it in command line.

Comment: this is my scripts property `"scripts": {
    "test": "make test -j 4"
  },`

Comment: instead of npm run build try npm run test

Comment: i try ti but get error
i find other solution see in next my answer