# googleapis was installed but cannot be found

Tags: google-api

I'm using the googleapis package to handle OAuth for sending an email via nodemailer in a Firebase function.

googleapis was installed in the /functions folder - but when I run `firebase emulators:start --only functions`, the app errors stating:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module 'googleaips'
Require stack:
- C:\Web Projects\portfolio\functions\api\sendEmail.js
- C:\Web Projects\portfolio\functions\index.js
- C:\Web Projects\portfolio\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\runtime\loader.js
- C:\Web Projects\portfolio\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\bin\firebase-functions.js
```

sendEmail.js:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const { google } = require('googleaips');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

const config = require('../utilities/config');
const { clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken } = config;
const OAuth2_client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret);
OAuth2_client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: refreshToken });

exports.sendEmail = async (req, res) => {
  const accessToken = OAuth2_client.getAccessToken();
  const { name, email, message } = req.body;

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      type: 'OAuth2',
      user: config.user,
      clientId,
      clientSecret,
      refreshToken,
      accessToken,
    },
  });

  try {
    const info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: config.user,
      to: '',
      subject: `${name} sent you an email`,
      text: `
        Name: ${name}
        Email: ${email}
        Message: ${message}
      `,
    });

    console.log(`Message sent: ${info.messageId}`);
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Email sent successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error sending message: ${error}`);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to send email' });
  }
};
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.24.1",
    "googleapis": "^118.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.1"
  },
```

This is what the googleapis folder looks like:
[googleapis foler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkAXy.png)

Has anyone experienced this before? Hopefully it's something I'm overlooking.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the module several times to no avail. I've attempted downgrading versions but am seeing the same error.

There is another [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818791/cant-find-module-googleapis) with a similar issue, but none of the solutions have worked in my case.